# File Syncronization on Localhost?

Tags: sync

I hope this is not the kind of "downvotes" question, first post here on superuser :)

I am looking for a particular file sync software - this is what I need to do:

I have a folder on my htdocs of XAMPP. Another one is on my desktop and contains the same files of the htdocs folder. I would like that when I edit some file on my desktop folder, it gets edited in the htdocs too.

I know I could create simply a shortcut or something like this, but this is NOT what I need.

Hoping you can give me some help with this question :)

Comment: Welcome to SU! Is one folder the master, e.g. a file deleted or changed in the slave copy gets replaced by the original? Or should the 2 directories be synchronized by the software you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole host of options available for this type of thing.  I have used AllwaySync and its new synchronization service that actively synchronizes in any direction you want between any two locations (local, cloud, ftp, whatever).  It is simple and powerful, and has a free version (but you're limited in the number of files you can synchronize).

Whatever solution you choose, you would just set up your folder on your desktop as the "source" and the htdocs folder as the "target" and it will push any changes you make in real time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) to drop `hardlink` of folder inside htdocs on Desktop. It may look like shortcut from 10000 feet, but its not really shortcut. Both hardlinked folders will have all characteristics of two separate folders: Both will have fully different paths. Even apps, command console etc can't find the reality. It means files inside it could be accessed with two different paths (just like two different synced folders).

If you aren't impressed (but tell me why), install Microsoft's [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15155) and setup a two-way sync.

P.S. I'll always recommend hardlinking over syncing for your case. Remember, sync would take time, but in case of hard link, time of propagation isn't defined because both sides are internally same.